# How can I open a link into a div that has data from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a site that has a page where I display some products that I have on my database. The products are displayed by small divs that are next to each other. I have put inside each div a link that I want to have the information of each product. The information will all have the same structure. I thought about having an

```
<a href="'.$row[id].".php".'">
```

and have an id.php file for each of the products. But that doesn t seem to make sense.

Here it is a bit of my code

```
<?php
mysql_select_db("myshop",$con);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM products',$con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $myimage = '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" />';

    echo  "<div id='appear'>" . $myimage . '<br />' . $row['title'] . 
"<br  />" . "<p style='color:red;' >" . "value " . $row['price'] . "€" . 
"</p>".  <a   href="'.$row[id].".php".'">. "details" . "<a>". 
</div>";                                       
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You're missing a quote before the last `</div>`.  Also, you should probably be using htmlspecialchars.

Comment: thanks, it was because I changed a bit my code before posting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an image.php...

```
<?php

mysql_select_db("myshop",$con);
id = (int)$_GET['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$id",$con);
print_r($result)

?>
```

And instead of this:

```
<a href="'.$row[id].".php".'">
```

Do this:

```
<a href="image.php?id='.$row[id].'">
```

Comment: You shouldn't assume that $_GET['id'] is set. What if someone goes to `image.php`?  `$id = (isset($_GET['id']) && is_string($_GET['id'])) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : null;`

Comment: @Corbin, the aim here wasn't to write production ready code. It was to illustrate the idea of using image.php.

Comment: Based on the level of knowledge the question asker has displayed, I would consider it a desirable addition.  By no means required for a correct answer though.  The comment was aimed more so at the OP than you as the snippet is not meant to be literally used.  I just hate seeing terrible PHP code (not yours -- I mean the dozen SQL injection, PHP notice riddled code people post in questions all day long), so I tend to be overly picky :).

Comment: I do believe you can't print directly from mysql_query, I think you need to use mysql_fetch_array first.

Comment: after making some small changes, it seems to work perfect: I will copy my code <?php

mysql_select_db("eshop",$con);
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$id",$con);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 print_r($result);
 }
 mysql_close($con);

?>
</div> the only weird thing is that shows only id=7 every time, bit the id in the link in my browser is correct.